# Why to check if function doesn't exists in functions.php?

Tags: theme-development, theme-twenty-eleven

I see in the twentyeleven theme, before most custom functions they check if it exists

```
<?php if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyeleven_comment' ) ) :
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A child theme may have declared these functions already with a slightly different inner logic. The `functions.php` from the child theme is loaded before the file from the parent theme. Without this check you would get the *Cannot redeclare …* error.

Plugins can create functions too, so this problem is not restricted to the themes that are written with child themes in mind.

Comment: I just want to reiterate - this is specifically done so child themes CAN overwrite existing functions and customize them, without customizing the parent theme.